# Batch-File Delim limitations

Tags: batch-file, command-line

```
@echo off
echo File Extionsion To Create List?
SET /p Ext=Ext:
echo %Ext%

for /f "tokens=1 delims=." %%g in ('dir /b *.%Ext%') do echo %%g >> Names.txt
```

How do you remove the last dot and the file extension without accidentally removing other dots. For example 10.01320.pdf will become 10.01320.

Comment: It's not delims thats the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your goal is to keep all the `.`'s in the file name just not the extension, you can simply use some [Parameter Extensions](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html). In the example of your goal, `%%~ng` will Expand `%%g` to a file Name without file extension or path.

```
@echo off
echo File Extionsion To Create List?
SET /p Ext=Ext:
echo %Ext%

for /f "tokens=1 delims=*" %%g in ('dir /b *.%Ext%') do echo %%~ng >> Names.txt
```